# UIViewControllerPreviewingDelegate methods not called when UISearchController presented

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchcontroller, 3dtouch

When searchController is not presented 3d touch works as expected and delegate methods called. But not called when searchController is active.

Creating of UISearchController looks like this

```
let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil) 
searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
searchController.delegate = self
searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
```